# SQL(Oracle) select the most common value (multiple tables)

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to know which seat was the most sold by individual halls?

TICKETS

```
IDTICKET   MOVIE_IDMOVIE     HALL_IDHALL      PRICE     SEAT    ROW
1           10               2                4         10      6
2           5                2                4         10      5
3           5                2                4         10      4
4           8                5                4         3       1
5           7                5                4         4       15
6           10               7                4         7       9
7           6                2                4         14      3
```

HALLS

```
IDHALL      PLACE_IDPLACE    NAME           NUMSEATS      EQUIPMENT   
1           5                A1             250           high  
2           5                B1             200           medium 
3           5                B2             200           medium 
4           5                C2             180           medium 
5           5                C2             180           medium 
6           9                old hall       120           low
```

Display should look like

1. B1 10
2. C2 3
   ...

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please don't just link to images containing your data, but add the data directly in your question text.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Instead of posting images of your data, please copy and paste a sample into your question above. To format it so it preserves whitespace, highlight it and click the `{}` editor toolbar button or ctl-k to create a formatted code block.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  b.Name, a.Seat
FROM    (SELECT     Hall, Seat, COUNT(1) AS SeatCount, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Hall ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC) AS SeatRank
        FROM        SEAT
        GROUP BY    Hall, Seat ) a
            INNER JOIN
        HALL b
        ON a.HALL_IDHALL = b.IDHALL 
WHERE   a.SeatRank = 1
```

Comment: Is there a possibility without using rank()?
I don't exactly understand how rank works.

Comment: it's ok but i'm looking for easily understandable option!

Answer (score 0):

select h.name,t.hall_idhall,h.idhall, max(t.seat) from tickets t, hall h where t.hall_idhall=h.idhall
group by h.name,t.hall_idhall,h.idhall

Try the above query

Comment: It gives me the highest number of the seat  not the most common seat.

Comment: Try using min function in place of max

Comment: Does't work.It gives me the minimum number of the seat.

Comment: sorry i think i am not able to understand your question, what data exactly you want to retrieve